# Numpy: np.where() with new dimensions

Tags: python, arrays, numpy

Python/numpy beginner so this should be easy to solve. Given a numpy 2d array of floats `map`, e.g.

```
map = [[0.19982308 0.19982308 0.19986019 ... 0.25456086 0.25463998 0.25463998]
      [0.19982308 0.19982308 0.19986019 ... 0.25456086 0.25463998 0.25463998]
      [0.19998285 0.19998285 0.20000038 ... 0.25459546 0.25466287 0.25466287]
      ...
      [0.4762167  0.4762167  0.47602317 ... 0.45300224 0.4541465  0.4541465 ]
      [0.4767613  0.4767613  0.47632453 ... 0.45406988 0.45538843 0.45538843]
      [0.4767613  0.4767613  0.47632453 ... 0.45406988 0.45538843 0.45538843]]
```

I want to carry out this operation:

```
new_map = np.where(map > 0.4, [255,255,255], [0,0,0])
```

That is, I want to create a new 2d array of the same dimensions but with RGB values instead of floats. Which RGB value is assigned to `new_map[x][y]` - white = [255,255,255] or black = [0,0,0] - is determined by whether `map[x][y]` is above a threshold (0.4 in the case above).

I get the following error message: `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes (512,512) (3,) (3,)`

I think I understand why - `np.where` restricts to the dimensions of `map` and I'm in effect trying to increase those dimensions by substituting the float for a nested array of length three.

Is there a workaround for this issue using `where` or any other numpy operation? Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a broadcast issue because `numpy.where` supposes that the arrays have compatible shape. Supposing that the expected output shape is `(y, x, 3)` you can do:

```
map_reshape = np.expand_dims(map, -1)
white = np.array([255, 255, 255]).reshape(1, 1, -1)
black = np.array([0, 0, 0]).reshape(1, 1, -1)
new_map = np.where(map_reshape >  0.4, white, black)
```

If the shape of map is `(y, x)` the shape of new_map will be `(y, x, 3)`

Comment: Thanks! Where does the threshold come into this? When I run this code I get new_map full of [255,255,255]

Comment: I'm sorry I forgot the threshold in the np.where, now it should work

Answer (score 2):

transform map to a np array first:

```
import numpy as np
#import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

#create map
map = np.random.rand(200,200)

#to show
#plt.matshow(map)


output_var = np.zeros([*map.shape,3])

output_var[map>0.4]=np.array([255,255,255])
```

Comment: Map is already a numpy 2d array (sorry, probably my fault for misleading variable name)

Comment: no problem, in that case, i recomend you to create a new array with the same dimensions as i did with `output_var` then change to `[255,255,255]` in the places where the condition meet (when `map>0.4`) you can inde the new `output_var` in these positions